# How can I invoke an action on selected input?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'd like to call a controller by passing inputs from a form via FormCollection parameters on selection of an item in an select element list (option). How can I do this?

```
<select id="selProj" class="selProj" name="Project">
    <option>Select Project</option>
    @foreach (ProjectModel.ProjectItem proj in Model.Projects) {
        <option value="@proj.Id" data-project="@proj.Number">@proj.Name</option>
    }
</select>
```

Comment: Why would you use form collection? Use a model, bind the select to your model property using `@Html.DropDownListFor()` and post back the model.

Comment: Well, I do have a model. I want the FormCollection because it just works. The model being used is a class that has sub classes. When passing via form, if a parameter I want passed into the controller method is a property of a sub class, the value of the sub class property that is populated by the asp.net mvc framework is null.  Do you have a fix for that?

Comment: You want to write 3 times as much code as necessary so that you lose strongly typed model binding, lose the ability to use client and server side validation, and all the other features of MVC. If _"it just works"_ then what is your question?

Comment: I think you missed the question I'm posting about "How can I invoke an action on selected input?"

Comment: And my comment was about how awful your code is.

Comment: Prove it is 'awful' code by demonstrating how 3 times more code is required to achieve the same purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery will do the magic for you in this case.

Simply create your form on the view with the selectlist and call the jquery function on the change event of selectlist like:

```
$("#selProj").change(function(){
   $("#sampleForm").submit();
});
```

and you will get the formcollection on the controller's action defined in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this also

```
<form action="test.do" method="POST">
    <select name="myselect" id="myselect" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think that would work perfectly, calling submit on the control (like the selected answer from user3265174).